# How to reference a DLL in scripted ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

So I have a ASPX page that we have been using like classic ASP because we do not have access to the code behind the file. All of the C# code is nested inside the ASPX page between `<%   %>` before the `<html>` tag begins. I need to reference an external DLL in order to do what I need to do. I noticed at the beginning of the ASPX there are some `.NET` references made.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>
```

Is there any way I can use a similar type of tag in order to reference a custom DLL ?

Comment: BTW, using it like Classic ASP, doesn't mean that this is classic ASP.  This is still ASP.NET, and you probably want to tag it that way.

Comment: True this is asp.net that I have been forced to use like classic asp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it works now I just added the Dll I wanted to reference to the bin and then added one more import namespace tag. I was confused because I thought I would have to specify a path, but not if the DLL is in the bin.

Answer (score 0):

Those are importing namespaces - that's *not* the same as adding a reference. (Assemblies and namespaces are different.)

You should be able to just add an assembly reference to the project in the normal way, in the "Project References" part of solution explorer. At that point, you should be able to import any namespaces that the assembly provides using the syntax you've already shown.

This is assuming these are .NET assemblies, of course. If you're trying to add a reference to a *native* DLL, you'd need to use P/Invoke just as with any other native DLL interop.

Comment: Unfortunately the only part of the project I have access to is the .aspx file. That's why I have been forced into the funky work around of adding c# to the aspx page in the first place.

Comment: @drzounds: Then as far as I know, you can't add a reference to another assembly. I would advise you to escalate this issue up to your manager or whatever - trying to work in a hobbled environment isn't a viable long term proposition, IMO.